# Set onItemClick to Custom adapter ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

When I had problems trying to fix the position of my listView items to the desired intent when filtered, and got info I could override the problem using a custom adapter, I have done that but I do not know how to assign the clicks to each items, please check below code:

```
public class IndexPageActivity extends Activity { 
ListView listView;
EditText editTextB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savfedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.indexpage);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pageList);
    editTextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchB);
    listView.setAdapter(new PagesAdapter(this));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);

}
}
class SingleRow {
String pagedata;
SingleRow(String pagedata){
    this.pagedata=pagedata;
}
}
class PagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnItemClickListener{
ArrayList<SingleRow> pagelist;
Context context;

PagesAdapter(Context c){
    context=c;
    pagelist = new ArrayList<SingleRow>();
    Resources res = c.getResources();
    String [] pagedatas = res.getStringArray(R.array.pages_data);
    for (int i=0;i<463;i++){
        pagelist.add(new SingleRow(pagedatas[i]));
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pagelist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pagelist.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewG) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)             context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewG,false);
    TextView pagetitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewRow);

    SingleRow temp=pagelist.get(i);

    pagetitle.setText(temp.pagedata);
    return row;
}
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int i, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I will appreciate any help given. Thank Yhu!

EDIT

Will this work?

```
 if (index == 0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page1.html");
    startActivity(i);
} else if (index == 1) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("keyHTML", "file:///android_asset/page2.html");
    startActivity(i);
```

Comment: assign click to each item? can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, like I used the simple_list_layout before and it does not have the getItem, getCount parameters, so it was pretty straightforward, now in the case of a custom adapter with this parameters, I'm confused on what step to go about it.

Comment: Write a toast under onItemClick method. You've already assigned click listener but you didn't use its callback as I see. And also please reuse your views at getView method.

Comment: @OluleyeIResþektIdowu click for textview in list row?

Comment: I want each item of the ListView to be able to open a new intent, I achieved this with the EDIT above using the simple layout, but when I apply a filter method to this simple layout, it messes up the intents. Thats why I went for customAdapter. I hope I'm making sense?

Comment: @OluleyeIResþektIdowu it will work except `int i` gives the index of listview in onitemClick

Comment: @aegean how do I reuse my views, what is the code to use?

Comment: @OluleyeIResþektIdowu you can see my answer for your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited ALL**

I just got what you need, I added a filter to your `baseAdapter` and then on text change within the `editText` You filter the `listView` and then you go to the activity needed.

here is the full code but you need to bare in mind that I have changed the following:

- I changed the pageList to ArrayList instead of
- There is a bug in filtering that when I erase what I wrote in the `EditText` it doesnt update the ListView, you need to figure out why.
- I changed the returned value of the function `getItem(int i)` from Object to String
- Within the `onItemClick` you have to search for the name instead of the position.

here is the code:

```
public class IndexPageActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{ 
ListView listView;
EditText editTextB;
PagesAdapter adapter1;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pageList);
            editTextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchB);
            adapter1 = new PagesAdapter(this);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter1);
            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

            editTextB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                        int arg3) {
                    // When user changed the Text
                    IndexPageActivity.this.adapter1.getFilter().filter(cs.toString());
                    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                        int arg2, int arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
    }


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i;
    String name = adapter1.getItem(position);
            Log.d("id", name);
    if (name.equals("Item1"))
    {
        i = new Intent(this, anActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (name.equals("Item2"))
    {
        i = new Intent(this, anActivity2.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
}


class SingleRow {
String pagedata;
SingleRow(String pagedata){
    this.pagedata=pagedata;
}
}
class PagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
ArrayList<String> pagelist;
List<String> arrayList;
Context context;
String [] pagedatas;

PagesAdapter(Context c){
    context=c;
    pagelist = new ArrayList<String>();
    Resources res = c.getResources();
    pagedatas = res.getStringArray(R.array.pages_data);
    for (int i=0;i<463;i++){
        pagelist.add(pagedatas[i]);
    }
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pagelist.size();
}

@Override
public String getItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pagelist.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return i;
}


@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewG) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)             context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,viewG,false);
    TextView pagetitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewRow);

    String temp=pagelist.get(i);

    pagetitle.setText(temp);
    return row;
}

public class filter_here extends Filter{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FilterResults Result = new FilterResults();
        // if constraint is empty return the original names
        if(constraint.length() == 0 ){
            Result.values = pagelist;
            Result.count = pagelist.size();
            return Result;
        }

        ArrayList<String> Filtered_Names = new ArrayList<String>();
        String filterString = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        String filterableString;

        for(int i = 0; i<pagelist.size(); i++){
            filterableString = pagelist.get(i);
            if(filterableString.toLowerCase().contains(filterString)){
                Filtered_Names.add(filterableString);
            }
        }
        Result.values = Filtered_Names;
        Result.count = Filtered_Names.size();

        return Result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pagelist = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    return new filter_here();
}
}
```

Comment: Cordeji! If I use the above code, wont the position mess itself up the way it did with the previous simple layout we made when filter is applied?

Comment: Yeah, you got me right... About the ListView not updating, quick search gave this - set adapter object in the list explicitly after filter is done. How do I put this boss?

Comment: In the above code you can filter the list according to the `EditText` and when you filter it and press the item it will take you to the right place! the thing is `getItem` return either an object or string. I dont know what to do in obj however, with string, you can use it in if statement to take you to the desired activity. check the `onItemClick` instead `item1` change it to the name of your item in the `R.id.pages_data`.

Comment: @Cordeji, I understand you, all was working well when I pasted the 3rd comment above, It works when I use the string and input the full name of the pagetitle. Its just the updating of the listView when the backspace is clicked on when the switch back from an iTem activity. Thanks a lot! Only problem I'm trynna figure out is the updating of the listView. Please check this Thanks - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840344/android-custom-arrayadapter-doesnt-refresh-after-filter if you will understand. I feel dumb.

Comment: HAHAHAHAI finally did it. Please check the final edit hope your problem is solved. I added the answer to your [qeustion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146760/bypassing-the-bug-in-filtering-that-does-not-update-listview-android/20152843#20152843):)

Answer (score 2):

Two different ways for it:

**1)** If you want to use something like this at onCreate of your activity;

`listView.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);`

You should implement `OnItemClickListener` to your activity:

```
IndexPageActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener
```

and implement its onItemClick method at your activity. (also remove `OnItemClickListener` interface from your custom adapter)

**2)** You can simply use below without implementing `OnItemClickListener` to any class:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO: handle row clicks here
    }
```

I suggest 2nd option. That is easier.

**Edit:** This not relevant to your problem but you should reuse your views/rows at listView. Change your getView method to:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
    }

    TextView pagetitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewRow);

    SingleRow temp=pagelist.get(i);

    pagetitle.setText(temp.pagedata);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip, the response given by Coderji, kinda works, except ofcourse the fact that the list doesnt get updated when backspace is clicked on or when after opening the intent and go back, the ListView doesnt update, could you check his code and maybe help, please? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Set your `setOnItemClickListenerlike` this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savfedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.indexpage);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.pageList);
    editTextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchB);
    listView.setAdapter(new PagesAdapter(this));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        //Your code here
        //int position is the index of the list item you clicked    
        //use it to manipulate the item for each click      
    }
});
}
```