# How to: Adding a bookmark feature with SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, webview

I've been thinking of ways to make this work, and I just dont get it.

I have several HTML files that are viewed using webView, I want to create a bookmark button on this WebView page.

If I create a DB with a table and three columns - containing the _id, the Title, and the URL, and populate it with the Titles and the URLs(from assets folder) and give each an IDs. When the "Add to Bookmark" button is clicked in the WebView activity, can it populate a ListView in the Favorites activity, and when the title is clicked, it locates the URL that corresponds in the SQLDB and then open it.

I have googled on SQLDB, but most of the tutorials do not make use of an already stored data in DB.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Alright use this code :

```
   // Saving the bookmark via ContentProvider
    final ContentValues bookmarkValues = new ContentValues();
    bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE, title);
    bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL, url);
    bookmarkValues.put(Browser.BookmarkColumns.BOOKMARK, 1);

    final Uri newBookmark = getContentResolver().insert(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, bookmarkValues);

    // Retrieving       
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, 
            null, null, null, Browser.BookmarkColumns.CREATED);

    cursor.moveToFirst();
    final String stitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("title"));
    final String surl = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("url"));
```