# How to filter ArrayAdapter?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on a homework planner app, and I'm looking for a way to display only certain elements in an ArrayList that holds Task objects. After the user clicks on a course from a list of course titles, the list of tasks that pertain to that course should be displayed. Currently, it shows a list of all tasks, no matter which course has been selected. Each Task object stores the course that it belongs to, in a field called mBelongsToCourse. I would like to be able to filter the ArrayList of all tasks that is used in my TaskAdapter to only show the tasks which belong to a specific course, but all my attempts have been fruitless.

Below is my TaskListFragment Class, which includes the TaskAdapter:

```
public class TaskListFragment extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Task> mTasks;
private  static String courseName;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    courseName = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("name");
    getActivity().setTitle(courseName);
    mTasks = TaskLab.get(getActivity()).getTasks();

    TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(mTasks);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}


@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    //Get the Task from the adapter
    Task t = ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);

    // Start TaskActivity for this task
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
    i.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, t.getId());
    startActivity(i);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_task_list, menu);
} 

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_new_task:
        Task task = new Task();
        task.setBelongsToCourse(courseName);
        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).addTask(task);
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), TaskActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(TaskFragment.EXTRA_TASK_ID, task.getId());
        //i.putExtra("cn", task.getBelongsToCourse());
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.task_list_item_context, menu);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
    ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);

    listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

        public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                long id, boolean checked) {
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }

        // ActionMode.Callback methods
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.task_list_item_context, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            return false;
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_item_delete_task:
                TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter)getListAdapter();
                TaskLab taskLab = TaskLab.get(getActivity());
                for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {   
                        taskLab.deleteTask(adapter.getItem(i));
                    }
                }
                mode.finish();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
        }
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = info.position;
    TaskAdapter adapter = (TaskAdapter)getListAdapter();
    Task task = adapter.getItem(position);

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_item_delete_task:
        TaskLab.get(getActivity()).deleteTask(task);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((TaskAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> {

    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, tasks);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, null);
        }

        // Configure the view for this Task
        Task t = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(t.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(t.getDate().toString());
        CheckBox completedCheckBox =
                (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_completedCheckBox);
        completedCheckBox.setChecked(t.isCompleted());
        return convertView;
    }


}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I've followed the advice of Ravind Maurya and Embattled Swag and updated my TaskAdapter:

```
private class TaskAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Task> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<Task> taskList;
    private Filter taskFilter;

    public TaskAdapter(ArrayList<Task> tasks) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, tasks);
        this.taskList = tasks;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_task, null);
        }

        // Configure the view for this Task
        Task t = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(t.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(t.getDate().toString());
        CheckBox completedCheckBox =
                (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.task_list_item_completedCheckBox);
        completedCheckBox.setChecked(t.isCompleted());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (taskFilter == null)
            taskFilter = new TaskFilter();

        return taskFilter;
    }

    private class TaskFilter extends Filter {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering (CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint == null | constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values = taskList;
                results.count = taskList.size();
            } else {
                ArrayList<Task> newTaskList = new ArrayList<Task>();
                for (Task t : taskList) {
                    if (t.getBelongsToCourse().toUpperCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toUpperCase())) {
                        newTaskList.add(t);
                    }
                }
                results.values = newTaskList;
                results.count = newTaskList.size();
            } return results;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {

            // Now we have to inform the adapter about the new list filtered
            if (results.count == 0)
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            else {
                taskList = (ArrayList<Task>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Now the problem I have is I don't know where to call .getFilter().filter(courseName) in order to filter the ArrayList.

Comment: Look this one it will helps you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11840344/android-custom-arrayadapter-doesnt-refresh-after-filter

Comment: use listView.setTextFilter

Answer (score 0):

I followed this example literally yesterday to come up with a solid filter: http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2012/10/android-listview-custom-filter-and.html

However; this example doesn't cover the case where you use the backspace and therefore the listview has to repopulate. You can follow the actual source code for the generic Filter here (it's at the bottom...essentially you'll just create a copy and then reduce the items of one of the lists): http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.0mOriginalValues

Comment: I've created a filter (see edit above) but I don't know how to implement it so that I can see the filtered list.

Comment: Ok, so I don't know how you're implementing it (are you doing checkboxes or something?), but whenever you want to filter it, you can call `adapter.getAdapter().filter(someText);` within the listener where `someText` is a `CharSequence`. That should filter the list.

Comment: Problem is, I don't really know how I'm implementing it either :/ What I want to do is be able to click on a course (doing so will set that course's name as courseName) and see a list of tasks that have a value for mBelongsToCourse that matches courseName. So I'm trying to filter by courseName, but I don't know where/how in my code to do that. All examples I've seen so far have to do with a user searching for something, and then the list is filtered by what they searched, but in my case it's the specific course name that is clicked that needs to filter the ArrayList. Thanks for your help!

Comment: well in the case I posted you can just replace `someText` to `courseName` (you correctly compare it in your custom Filter class) . I think the best solution for your would be a `Spinner`.

Comment: Okay. What is the spinner for though?